# Shower water shuts off

Tags: shower

I have a single lever shower lever, turn counter clockwise to turn on water and further you go hotter the water gets. My problem is when i turn lever to far counter clockwise to get the water to hot the water shuts off.. if i turn back a little the water pressure is great but only luke warm water.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do you need to do to get full hot; turn it all the way off first?

Comment: Do you have a tankless water heater or a tank one?

Comment: How old is the construction? Asking because it sounds like malfunctioning anti-scald valve.

Comment: ...Or simply a mis-adjusted anti-scald valve (many are adjustable, at least the built-into-the-shower-valve types, based on the instructions of shower valves I've installed.)

Comment: I have a tank water heater, i pulled handle and back plat of to expose piping i see no anti scold valve..handle can turn freely almsot 180 degrees however, when i turn to get water hot which is almost staright up and down water still cuts off..i turn back a little until water flows again but then water temp drops back to just warm